# Quiero recoger un archivo xml con la estructura de un libro, lo que me interesa es sacar las unidades y mostrar cuantas tiene

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Este es mi codigo en NW.js o JavaScript

[image: funcion leer]

****función analizarxml****

```
function analizarSeccionXML(path){

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var listaUnidades=[];

        var promesaLectura= leerXML(path);
        promesaLectura.then(function(data){
            console.log("Comenzando a analizar..")
            //console.log(data.CDInteractive.Unidad)
            data.CDInteractive.Unidad.forEach(function(unidad, index){
                //console.log(actividades);

                unidad.Unidad.forEach(function(unidad, index){
                    //console.log(actividad);
                    if(unidad.Tipo._text=="Unidad"){
                        listaUnidades.push({"archivo":unidad.Unidad, "estructura":unidad})
                    }

                    //console.log(index+"-->"+actividades.Actividades.Actividad.length)
                    if(index==unidad.Unidad.length-1){
                        console.log("TERMINO!!")
                        resolve({"unidades":listaUnidades});
                    }

                })
            })
        }, function(err){
            alert("se genero un error al leer el archivo xml")
        }
}
```

Pero no me lee el archivo, agradecería pudieran ayudarme a corregirlo.

**Esta es la estructura del XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CDInteractive>
    <Nombre idioma="S" version="P17">6 Grado</Nombre>
    <NumPagesPDF>204</NumPagesPDF>
    <ISBN></ISBN>
    <Autor></Autor>
    <PDF>
        <Unidad-Pagina id="1">1-Español</Unidad-Pagina>
    <Unidad-Pagina id="2">3-MATEMÁTICAS</Unidad-Pagina>
    </PDF>
    
  <Unidad id="1">
      <Actividades>
        <Actividad id="1">
          <!--Video 01 -->
          <Pagina>2</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Habilidad Lectora - "Antecedente histórico de la geometría"</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Video</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct name="Antecedente histórico de la geometría">Video 1</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion></Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        <Actividad id="2">
          <!-- Audio 1-->
          <Pagina>2</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Ángulos</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Audio</Tipo>
          <Track>Track01</Track>
          <NombreAct></NombreAct>
          <Instruccion></Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        <Actividad id="3">
          <!--Juego1 Colocar imagen1-->
          <Pagina>1</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Clasificación de los ángulos</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct>Colocar_imagenes_1</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion>Coloca la imagen en el lugar correcto base al planteamiento, pregunta u oración presentada para cada una.</Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        
        <Actividad id="4">
          <!--Juego02 Ahorcado-->
          <Pagina>1</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Triángulos</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct>Ahorcado</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion>Completa la frase o palabra relacionada con el concepto planteado.</Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego>
            <pregunta id = "1">
              <frase>Es una figura geométrica determinada por tres segmentos (no alineados) que se cortan dos a dos en tres puntos llamados vértices.</frase>
              <palabra>Triángulo</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="2">
              <frase>Los ________ de recta son los lados del triángulo.</frase>
              <palabra>segmentos</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="3">
              <frase>Un triángulo contiene 3 lados, 3 ángulos ________ y 3 ángulos exteriores.</frase>
              <palabra>interiores</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="4">
              <frase>Un triángulo se puede indicar con tres letras latinas mayúsculas en los ________, que a la vez representan los ángulos.</frase>
              <palabra>vértices</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="5">
              <frase>Los ________ también se pueden escribir con letras del alfabeto griego.</frase>
              <palabra>ángulos</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="6">
              <frase>Este triángulo tiene los tres lados de la misma medida.</frase>
              <palabra>Equilátero</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="7">
              <frase>Es el triángulo que tiene dos lados iguales y uno desigual.</frase>
              <palabra>Isósceles</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="8">
              <frase>Este triángulo tiene los tres lados de diferente medida.</frase>
              <palabra>Escaleno</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="9">
              <frase>Este triángulo ocurre cuando tiene un ángulo interior recto.</frase>
              <palabra>Rectángulo</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="10">
              <frase>Este triángulo ocurre si uno de sus ángulos interiores es obtuso o mayor de 90 grados.</frase>
              <palabra>Obtusángulo</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="11">
              <frase>Este triángulo ocurre cuando sus tres ángulos interiores son menores de 90 grados.</frase>
              <palabra>Acutángulo</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="12">
              <frase>En todo triángulo, la suma de sus ángulos ________ es igual a 180°.</frase>
              <palabra>internos</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="13">
              <frase>En todo triángulo, la suma de sus ángulos ________ es igual a 360°.</frase>
              <palabra>externos</palabra>
            </pregunta>
            <pregunta id ="14">
              <frase>En todo triángulo, un ángulo externo es igual a la suma de los dos ángulos interiores no ________ a él.</frase>
              <palabra>adyacentes</palabra>
            </pregunta>
          </EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        
        <Actividad id="5">
          <!--Juego03 Relacionar1-->
          <Pagina>1</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Rectas y puntos notables</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct>Relacionar_1</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion>Lee los conceptos, relaciónalos y coloca el número donde corresponda.</Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        <Actividad id="6">
          <!--Interactividad1-->
          <Pagina>1</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Semejanza y congruencia</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct>Interactividad_TL_1</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion></Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        
        <Actividad id="7">
          <!--Video 02 -->
          <Pagina>2</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Habilidad Lectora - "Las abejas"</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Video</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct name="Las abejas">Video 2</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion></Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        <Actividad id="8">
          <!--Audio02-->
          <Pagina>2</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Polígonos</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Audio</Tipo>
          <Track>Track02</Track>
          <NombreAct></NombreAct>
          <Instruccion></Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        <Actividad id="9">
          <!--Juego 04 Arrastrar-->
          <Pagina>1</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Elementos del polígono</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct>Arrastrar_palabra_1</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion>Arrastre y suelte las palabras según corresponda la imagen.</Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>
        <Actividad id="10">
          <!--Interactividad2-->
          <Pagina>1</Pagina>
          <NombActividad>Áreas de los poligonos</NombActividad>
          <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
          <Track></Track>
          <NombreAct>Interactividad_TL_2</NombreAct>
          <Instruccion></Instruccion>
          <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
        </Actividad>        
    </Unidad>
  
    <Unidad id="2">        
        <Actividades>
            <Actividad id="1">
                <Pagina>4</Pagina>  
                <NombActividad>Habilidad Lectora - "William Mulholland, el ingeniero autodidacta"</NombActividad>
                <Tipo>Video</Tipo>
                <Track></Track>
                <NombreAct name="William Mulholland, el ingeniero autodidacta">Video 5</NombreAct>
                <Instruccion></Instruccion>
                <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
            </Actividad>  
      <!-- Video 1 -->

      <Actividad id="2">
        <Pagina>3</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Inecuaciones</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
        <Track></Track>
        <NombreAct>Serpientes_y_escaleras</NombreAct>
        <Instruccion>Contesta correctamente las preguntas para poder llegar a la meta.</Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego>
          
          <pregunta id="1">
            <contenidoP>Se define como una expresión matemática definida como una desigualdad en la que aparece una incógnita:</contenidoP>
            <correct>Inecuación.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Ecuación.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Función.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="2">
            <contenidoP>¿Qué grado debe de tener una inecuación para denominarla de primer grado o lineal?</contenidoP>
            <correct>Uno.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Cero.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Dos.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="3">
            <contenidoP>Para resolver una inecuación es necesario encontrar ________ de la incógnita para los cuales se cumple la desigualdad planteada.</contenidoP>
            <correct>los valores</correct>
            <OpcionB>las propiedades</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>los intervalos</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="4">
            <contenidoP>¿De qué manera se representa la solución de una inecuación?</contenidoP>
            <correct>Por un intervalo.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Por una transición.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Por un segmento.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="5">
            <contenidoP>¿Qué leyes se deben de tener presentes para resolver una inecuación?</contenidoP>
            <correct>Leyes de tricotomía.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Leyes de trasposición.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Leyes de tensiones.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="6">
            <contenidoP>Se llama ________ entre dos conjuntos A y B a la manera ordenada de asociar o agrupar los elementos de cada uno de ellos y es el resultado de la multiplicación de A por B.</contenidoP>
            <correct>relación</correct>
            <OpcionB>conjunto</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>función</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="7">
            <contenidoP>¿Cómo se llama la regla de correspondencia que hay entre una variable independiente x que define uno y solo un valor de otra dependiente y?</contenidoP>
            <correct>Función.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Relación.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Conjunto.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="8">
            <contenidoP>¿De qué manera se escribe la notación de una función?</contenidoP>
            <correct>y = f (x)</correct>
            <OpcionB>x=f(y)</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>f(x)=x</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="9">
            <contenidoP>“El doble de una cantidad x” es una regla de correspondencia. ¿Cuál es su símbolo funcional de la función?</contenidoP>
            <correct>f (x) = 2x</correct>
            <OpcionB>V(x) = x³</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>v(t) = gt</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="10">
            <contenidoP>¿A qué regla de correspondencia pertenece el símbolo funcional v(x) = x³?</contenidoP>
            <correct>El volumen V de un cubo cuyo lado es x.</correct>
            <OpcionB>El doble de una cantidad x.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>El volumen V de un cono en función de su radio r.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="11">
            <contenidoP>La regla de correspondencia “La velocidad v de un cuerpo en caída libre como función del tiempo t (g es la gravedad)”. ¿A qué símbolo funcional pertenece?</contenidoP>
            <correct>v(t) = gt</correct>
            <OpcionB>f (x) = 2x</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>V(x) = x³</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="12">
            <contenidoP>Es el conjunto de valores de la recta numérica que se le pueden asignar a la variable independiente de una función:</contenidoP>
            <correct>Dominio.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Rango.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Codominio.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="13">
            <contenidoP>Es el conjunto de números reales que puede asumir la función f (x) conforme la variable independiente x toma valores en todo su dominio.</contenidoP>
            <correct>Rango.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Dominio.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Codominio.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="14">
            <contenidoP>¿Con que nombre se le conoce al rango?</contenidoP>
            <correct>Imagen de x bajo f.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Imagen de y bajo x.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Imagen de x bajo y.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta id="15">
            <contenidoP>¿En qué tipo de función debe evitarse que el denominador de su expresión algebraica valga cero y que una raíz par contenga un valor menor de cero?</contenidoP>
            <correct>Función racional.</correct>
            <OpcionB>Función radical.</OpcionB>
            <OpcionC>Función irracional.</OpcionC>
          </pregunta>
        </EstructuraJuego>
      </Actividad>
      <!-- Juego 1 Serpientes y Escaleras-->
      
      <Actividad id="3">
        <Pagina>3</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Graficación de funciones</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
        <Track></Track>
        <NombreAct>Interactividad_Concep_Map_2</NombreAct>
        <Instruccion></Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
      </Actividad>
      <!-- Interactividades 1 -->

      <Actividad id="4">
        <Pagina>3</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Graficación de funciones</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
        <Track></Track>
        <NombreAct>Burbujas</NombreAct>
        <Instruccion>Selecciona la burbuja correcta referente a la pregunta, planteamiento o enunciado.</Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego>
          <pregunta>
            <numP>1</numP>
            <frase>¿Qué tipo de funciones son las que resultan al realizar operaciones algebraicas como la adición, sustracción, multiplicación, división, radicación y potenciación con funciones polinomiales?</frase>
            <correcta>Funciones 
algebraicas.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Funciones 
trascendentes.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Funciones 
continuas.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>2</numP>
            <frase>¿Qué ejemplo sobre funciones algebraicas puedes encontrar?</frase>
            <correcta>f(x)=2</correcta>
            <opcion1>f(x)=2tanx</opcion1>
            <opcion2>f(x)=x²</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>3</numP>
            <frase>Se llaman así para distinguirlas de las algebraicas y son las trigonométricas, exponenciales y logarítmicas:</frase>
            <correcta>Funciones 
trascendentes.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Funciones 
algebraicas.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Funciones 
continuas.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>

          <pregunta>
            <numP>4</numP>
            <frase>¿Qué ejemplo sobre funciones trascendentes puedes encontrar?</frase>
            <correcta>f(x)=2tanx</correcta>
            <opcion1>f(x)=2</opcion1>
            <opcion2>f(x)=x²</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>5</numP>
            <frase>¿Cuáles son las funciones que cuya gráfica no tiene interrupciones, saltos o huecos?</frase>
            <correcta>Funciones 
continuas.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Funciones 
discontinuas.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Funciones 
uno a uno o 
inyectivas.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>6</numP>
            <frase>¿Qué funciones son las que tienen espacios indefinidos en su gráfica? </frase>
            <correcta>Funciones 
discontinuas.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Funciones 
continuas.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Funciones 
uno a uno o 
inyectivas.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>

          <pregunta>
            <numP>7</numP>
            <frase>¿Qué tipo de funciones resultan cuando dos valores diferentes de la variable independiente x tienen también diferente rango f (x)?</frase>
            <correcta>Funciones 
uno a uno o 
inyectivas.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Funciones 
discontinuas.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Funciones 
continuas.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>8</numP>
            <frase>¿Cuáles son las funciones en donde alguna recta horizontal corta su gráfica más de una vez?</frase>
            <correcta>Funciones 
sobreyectivas.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Funciones 
biyectivas.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Funciones 
uno a uno o 
inyectivas.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>9</numP>
            <frase>f (x) con g(x) se escribe como (f + g)(x), y se define como f (x) + g(x). ¿Qué operación obtenemos?</frase>
            <correcta>Suma.</correcta>
            <opcion1>Resta.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Multiplicación.</opcion2>
          </pregunta>

          <pregunta>
            <numP>10</numP>
            <frase>La resta de f (x) con g(x) se escribe como (f −g)(x). ¿De qué manera se define?</frase>
            <correcta>f(x)-g(x)</correcta>
            <opcion1>f(-x)-g(-x)</opcion1>
            <opcion2>f(x)-g(-x)</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>11</numP>
            <frase>La multiplicación de f (x) con g(x) se escribe como (fg)(x). ¿Cómo se define? </frase>
            <correcta>f(x)⋅g(x)</correcta>
            <opcion1>f =(x)⋅g(x)</opcion1>
            <opcion2>f(x)= g(x)</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>12</numP>
            <frase>La división de f (x) con g(x) se escribe como (f/g) (x), y se define como:</frase>
            <correcta>f(x)/g(x);
g(x)≠0</correcta>
            <opcion1>f(x)/g(x);
g(x)=0</opcion1>
            <opcion2>f(x)/g(x);
g(x)</opcion2>
          </pregunta>
 </EstructuraJuego>
</Actividad>
      <!-- Juego 2  Burbujas-->

      <Actividad id="5">
        <Pagina>3</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Transformaciones gráficas</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
        <Track></Track>
        <NombreAct>Verdadero_falso_gráfico_1</NombreAct>
        <Instruccion>Selecciona la imagen correcta para la pregunta o planteamiento.</Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
      </Actividad>
      <!-- Juego 3 VFG -->

      <Actividad id="6">
        <Pagina>3</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Transformaciones en las gráficas de las funciones</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
        <Track></Track>
        <NombreAct>Sniper</NombreAct>
        <Instruccion>Escoge la respuesta correcta  de cada pregunta hasta completar el juego.</Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>1</numP>
            <frase>¿Cuáles son las transformaciones que se pueden lograr al aplicar ciertas propiedades algebraicas a sus ecuaciones con el propósito de reducir y facilitar el trabajo al momento de bosquejarlas?</frase>
            <opcion1>Transformaciones horizontales.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Transformaciones verticales.</opcion2>
            <correcta>Transformaciones de las gráficas de las funciones.</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>2</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f(x) se cambia por y = f(x)+c, entonces su gráfica sufre una ________ hacia arriba c unidades.</frase>
            <opcion1>traslación combinada</opcion1>
            <opcion2>traslación horizontal</opcion2>
            <correcta>traslación vertical</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>3</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f(x) se transforma en y=f(x)–c. ¿Hacia dónde va su  traslación?</frase>
            <opcion1>Izquierda.</opcion1>
            <opcion2>Arriba.</opcion2>
            <correcta>Abajo.</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>4</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f(x) se cambia por y = f(x+c), entonces su gráfica sufre una ________ a la izquierda c unidades.</frase>
            <opcion1>traslación combinada</opcion1>
            <opcion2>traslación vertical</opcion2>
            <correcta>traslación horizontal</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>5</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f (x) se transforma en y = f (x - c). ¿En qué unidades va su traslación es hacia la derecha?</frase>
            <opcion1>V</opcion1>
            <opcion2>U</opcion2>
            <correcta>C</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>6</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f (x) se cambia por y = -f (x), entonces su gráfica se ________ con respecto al eje x. </frase>
            <opcion1>dilata</opcion1>
            <opcion2>alarga</opcion2>
            <correcta>refleja</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>7</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f (x) se transforma en y = f (-x). ¿Con respecto a que eje va la reflexión?</frase>
            <opcion1>Z</opcion1>
            <opcion2>X</opcion2>
            <correcta>Y</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>8</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y = f(x) la cambiamos por y=cf(x), entonces su gráfica se ________ verticalmente c unidades.</frase>
            <opcion1>dilata</opcion1>
            <opcion2>refleja</opcion2>
            <correcta>alarga</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>9</numP>
            <frase>Si la función y=f(x)  se transforma en y= 1 c f (x) la gráfica se ________verticalmente c unidades.</frase>
            <opcion1>refleja</opcion1>
            <opcion2>alarga</opcion2>
            <correcta>comprime</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta>
            <numP>10</numP>
            <frase>¿De qué forma se define y se escribe la composición de f(x)?</frase>
            <opcion1>(f°g)(x) = f°(g(x))</opcion1>
            <opcion2>(f g)(x) = f(g(x))</opcion2>
            <correcta>(f°g)(x) = fg(x))</correcta>
          </pregunta>

        </EstructuraJuego>
      </Actividad>
      <!-- Juego 4 Sniper -->

      <Actividad id="7">
        <Pagina>4</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Inecuaciones</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Audio</Tipo>
        <Track>Track07</Track>
        <NombreAct></NombreAct>
        <Instruccion></Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
      </Actividad>
      <!-- Audio 1 -->

      <Actividad id="8">
        <Pagina>4</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Dominio y rango</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Audio</Tipo>
        <Track>Track08</Track>
        <NombreAct></NombreAct>
        <Instruccion></Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego></EstructuraJuego>
      </Actividad>
      <!-- Audio 2 -->

      <Actividad id="9">
        <Pagina>3</Pagina>
        <NombActividad>Modelo general de las funciones polinomiales</NombActividad>
        <Tipo>Juego</Tipo>
        <Track></Track>
        <NombreAct>El_juego_de_la_Oca</NombreAct>
        <Instruccion>Contesta correctamente las preguntas para poder llegar a la meta.</Instruccion>
        <EstructuraJuego>
          
          <pregunta num="1">
            <contenido>La expresión algebraica general: P(x) = anxn + an-1 xn-1 + an-2 xn-2+ … + a1x + a0. ¿Qué nombre recibe?</contenido>
            <respuestaA>Polinomio P(x) de grado n.</respuestaA>
            <respuestaB>Polinomio P(x) de grado a.</respuestaB>
            <respuestaC>Polinomio P(x) de grado x.</respuestaC>
            <correcta>A</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta num="2">
            <contenido>En la expresión algebraica general: P(x) = anxn + an-1 xn-1 + an-2 xn-2+ … + a1x + a0. ¿Cómo se llama an≠0?</contenido>
            <respuestaA>Coeficiente principal del polinomio.</respuestaA>
            <respuestaB>Coeficiente del polinomio.</respuestaB>
            <respuestaC>Coeficiente constante.</respuestaC>
            <correcta>A</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta num="3">
            <contenido>La expresión algebraica general: P(x) = anxn + an-1 xn-1 + an-2 xn-2+ … + a1x + a0. ¿Cuáles son los coeficientes del polinomio?</contenido>
            <respuestaA>a0, a1, a2,…, an</respuestaA>
            <respuestaB>an ≠ 0</respuestaB>
            <respuestaC>a0</respuestaC>
            <correcta>A</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta num="4">
            <contenido>¿Cuál es el coeficiente constante de la expresión algebraica general: P(x) = anxn + an-1 xn-1 + an-2 xn-2+ … + a1x + a0?</contenido>
            <respuestaA>a0, a1, a2,…, an</respuestaA>
            <respuestaB>an ≠ 0</respuestaB>
            <respuestaC>a0</respuestaC>
            <correcta>A</correcta>
          </pregunta>
          
          <pregunta num="5">
            <contenido>¿Qué modelo corresponde a la ecuación de una línea recta de la forma f(x) = mx+b?</contenido>
            <respuestaA>Modelo gráfico.</respuestaA>
            <respuestaB>Modelo algebraico.</respuestaB>
            <respuestaC>Modelo de representación.</respuestaC>
            <correcta>A</correcta>
          </pregunta>     
      </Actividades>     
    </Unidad>
</CDInteractive>
```

Comment: Que quiere decir que no te lee el archivo? que error tira?

Comment: y otra pregunta.. que hacemos con 30000 lineas de un xml?

Comment: Si el XML que añadiste es el mismo que estás probando tiene un error de formato así que por eso no te debe estar funcionando, parece que le faltan caracteres